# What does ret reinterpret_cast do?

Tags: c++, haxe, hxcpp

```
#define HX_DEFINE_DYNAMIC_FUNC0(class,func,ret) \
Dynamic __##class##func(hx::Object *inObj) \
{ \
      ret reinterpret_cast<class *>(inObj)->func(); return Dynamic(); \
}; \
Dynamic class::func##_dyn() \
{\
   return hx::CreateMemberFunction0(this,__##class##func); \
}
```

The above CreateMemberFunction0 is a struct that holds information about the function. The function __##class##func is presumably at some point executed and its result is passed to relevant code. However, I am confused by this because it appears that the execution of the function returns the execution of a function called Dynamic? Dynamic is also a class (for those unfamiliar) with hxcpp/haxe.

1. Is Dynamic() an execution of a function or is it a no-argument construction on the stack of an object?
2. What is the ret keyword?
3. If 1 is correct, how is the result of execution of the function passed?

Comment: It's a macro that expends to a function. `ret` is not a keyword but a parameter passed to the macro.

Comment: I can't believe I didnt see that :( Sry!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Dynamic() an execution of a function or is it a no-argument construction on the stack of an object?

It must be the latter because the return type of the function being defined is also `Dynamic`.

> What is the ret keyword?

It's not a keyword, it's a parameter passed to the macro. A Google search turned up these two [use cases](https://fermmmtools.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/other/examples/Haxe/console/bin/cpp/windows/obj/src/List.cpp) of that macro:

```
HX_DEFINE_DYNAMIC_FUNC0(List_obj,first,return)
HX_DEFINE_DYNAMIC_FUNC0(List_obj,clear,(void))
```

In the first case the function `reinterpret_cast`s the result of the `(inObj)->func()` function call to a `List_obj *`. For the code to work, `Dynamic` must have an implicit conversion constructor that takes a `List_obj *`.

In the second case the result of the `reinterpret_cast` is discarded and a default constructed `Dynamic()` object is returned.